# How to handle timezones?

Tags: timezone

I know this question has been asked a few times, but I think I'm interested in a slightly different aspect of it.

My site has two kinds of users. Let's call them Frontend (FE) users, and backend (BE) users. FE users are unauthenticated (they do not have user accounts and thus no timezone), but they can create bookings and choose specific dates and times.

BE users have user accounts. They can choose their own timezone. When they view a booking it should display the time exactly as the FE user entered it. If I convert this time to use the BE's timezone the time will be skewed.

Other datetimes, such as when the booking was created, *should* be converted to the BE's timezone, however.

For example, if a FE user creates a booking for 2014-03-11 at 5:00pm, it will be stored in the database as 2014-03-11 5:00pm UTC. When the BE user views it, it will be pulled out of the database, left in UTC and displayed as 5:00pm.

If they look at when the booking was created, it might have been recorded at 2:00pm UTC, but if I display 2:00pm to the BE user he might be confused because it might even appear in the future (if UTC is ahead of his local timezone)!

So, as far as I'm aware, the only way to deal with this is to be very careful which dates I convert the timezone for, and which I leave alone, right? There's no easy way to deal with this so that I can use a consistent timezone throughout my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... the only way to deal with this is to be very careful which dates I convert the timezone for, and which I leave alone, right?

In general, that's a good idea.  Working with time means understanding the *context* of what you're working with.  If you try to just set it once and forget it, you'll probably have at least one part of your app that behaves incorrectly.

In your particular use case, you describe "bookings" as being entered in an unspecified time zone.  But then you say that you are storing them as UTC.  If bookings are truly disassociated from any time zone, then you should *not* introduce UTC when working with them.  Just leave them unspecified.  (If you provide details about your language and DB, I can recommend specific data types.)

HOWEVER - there might be a context you're not considering.  When you make a booking, is it for a specific *location*? If so, then the time zone of the location might be considered instead of the time zone of the user. You might use the location's time zone to convert to UTC, or you might store a "date-time-offset" combined value that is normalized to the location's time zone.  Either would allow for reasonable conversions of the booking time, if that's something you need.  Only you can decide whether this makes sense for your app or not.

With regard to the *recorded* time, that's a different context.  It can certainly be in UTC, and then just converted to the time zone of whomever is viewing it.

Comment: I'm using MariaDB. I *think* the way Maria/MySQL work is that all datetimes are saved as UTC and the converted to the DB's timezone setting when you pull the data out (which I've also set to UTC). Actually, that might only apply to `TIMESTAMP`s, I think `DATETIME`s don't have a timezone? Manual is a bit unclear on this. Bookings *do* have associated locations, but those are user-entered too; it may be a bit hard to look up the timezone for it. I don't think I want to go down that road if I don't need to.

Comment: Reference [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date-and-time-data-types/).    Also, MariaDB is derived from MySQL, so reference [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html).  `DATETIME` doesn't have a time zone.  `TIMESTAMP` is based on UTC.

Comment: Thus, I would recommend you use `DATETIME` for the time of the booking itself, and `TIMESTAMP` for recording the time that the booking was placed.  See, different contexts, different data types. :)

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` doesn't actually store the timezone though. It just converts to and from whatever timezone MySQL is set to, which seems kind of pointless and potentially dangerous if it changes. Further, it's restricted to 1970-2038, not that that should be a concern for my intended usage unless my app lives for 24 years. Nevertheless, what would be the advantage of using a `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` is *stored* with reference to UTC, so it's an exact instant in time.  When you interact with it, you use the local time in the current time zone setting, which *can* be set per connection. (see  7th paragraph [here]https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)).  You can also use the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` function if you like.  But sure, you could just use `DATETIME` for that as well. It's just that you will manually need to ensure the value is in UTC.

Comment: I did find another advantage -- `DATETIME` cannot handle the hour between 1 and 2am each fall in timezones that have summer time, whereas `TIMESTAMP` can. I think I'll do it the way you've suggested. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

1. If FE users put dates in UTC - you can either display them as UTC for BE or convert them to BE timezone - both variants are ok, just mention timezone to BE users and they will not be confused
2. FE users should indicate timezone during booking creation, then you will convert it to UTC to store in DB and then you can display in BE user's timezone

**the main thing - always indicate timezone during output near actual date time value**

Comment: FE users don't know they're entering dates in UTC and I can't ask them to choose a timezone. It's implicit based on where the booking takes place. Basically, the timezone is unknown to the system but a human would instantly know what timezone they mean based on common knowledge. Thus I can't specify the timezone to the BE user either because I don't know what it is. Any timestamps I record, however, I do know the timezone of.

Comment: I guess that answers my own question. I can't display or convert what I don't know.

Comment: @Mark right, you need to ask users about timezone, other way system will not work, you can simplify this process - but assuming some timezone (based on ip or javascript) on creation form, but with possibility to change it by FE user

Comment: Why wouldn't the system work? I can't use IP or JavaScript either. Users' system clock can be wrong, or they can be physically outside of the intended timezone. Can't ask the user the enter it; one extra field is too many and the FE user is almost guaranteed to screw it up at some point.

Comment: @Mark system will not work as you actually don't know what numbers (entered by FE) mean, you cannot use "unknown" time, so you have to add field and use any technique to set default value to it

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem. I just want to record the date and time entered by the FE and then display it exactly as is to the BE. It could probably be a text field for all it matters. I don't need to do date math on it or anything. Only thing I might want to do is format it a little differently.

Comment: @Mark then suppose it as UTC, and display **without** any kind of conversion, but you want to add conversion because _BE user he might be confused because it might even appear in the future_, so you either add timezone for FE users or display it as is even if it will be confusion

Comment: @Mark I suppose your problem is because you're thinking that DateTime exists, but no, there is no such entity as DateTime, it does not make any sense, you should always think about DateTimeInSomeTimeZone - this make sense

Comment: Nonono, you're mixing two different things. The bit about "he might be confused because it might even appear in the future" is with regards to the date the booking was created. That's a timestamp; we can safely convert that to any timezone. There are two kinds of dates: user entered ones, and automatic timestamps. The former we can't convert because we don't have timezone information, the latter we can freely convert. The former we have to display as-is without timezone info, the latter we can append the timezone if it adds clarity.